# Why use two colors as the background of gravatars?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, design, profile-page

I don't know whether this is added in a long time ago and I just didn't notice until now or this is a new thing:

[image]

Note: this user has been chosen for no specific reason. I just happened to be looking at his profile

As you can see there, the upper part of the background has a grey color while the lower part has a white color. That is so weird!

Is there any specific reasons for this? Maybe a bug?

Comment: Having two background colors for id/profile box is a "thing". If you go look at profiles on other sites, like Twitter or any Bootstrap template, they'll do the same thing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

While it appears to be somewhat of a stylistic choice, there's actually some UX design behind that.

Gravatars are one color on a white that is identical to the white for the background. The grey rectangle allows the human eye to see the boundaries of the image. In the places where the image is white on white, our brain is able to extrapolate the boundaries and knows where the borders are without needing the grey.

---

Just as a note: the background is actually used for all user icons. Even with [a close shade of grey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2257664/a-l), it still helps as an indicator for where the boundaries are.

Comment: Why not just surround the whole thing then?  If you're worried about taking up too much space below, the entire background / padding could be reduced some, since you wouldn't have to rely on optical illusions to suggest where the edge was.  (It doesn't look like deliberate Web design, it looks like Yet Another CSS Bounding Box Error.  ...which I guess is the same thing.)

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase what if the background of the image was grey?

Comment: @breeze:  The stated intent of the light grey almost-square is to provide a contrasting for specific images with _white_ backgrounds, so that is not a concern.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase: what if the light gray was the color picked by gravatar for the shapes? Then the shapes would meld with the background! The 2-background colors is agnostic to the colors picked by the gravatar.

Comment: @MatthieuM.:  I honestly don't know if that can happen.  ([Gravatar's "Image Requests" docs](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/) don't even mention possible "identicon" colors.)  But the accepted answer stated that the problem was the white background, and didn't mention any problems with light grey foregrounds.  In addition, this same problem apparently doesn't need to be solved at all in questions, where the asker's name, icon, and other details are surrounded entirely by light blue-grey, without any need for weird optical illusions.  And answers use no background at all.

Answer (score -5):

That's the design.

It was chosen because the designer decided he liked it that way.

Comment: Surely there is something rational behind this, not only the designers' whims. Maybe to provide contrast regardless of the avatar's dominant color?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - that's probably it :)